# Altair: rotate text by value specified in feature

Tags: python, vega, vega-lite, altair

I would like to rotate text based on a value specified in a column of my pandas DataFrame. It seems the `angle` parameter of `text_config` only takes float values and no feature name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [0, 1, 0, -1],
        "y": [1, 0, -1, 0],
        "name": ["UP", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "LEFT"],
        "angle": {180, 270, 0, 90},
    }
)

alt.Chart(data).encode(x="x", y="y", text="name").mark_text(angle='angle')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, text angle is not available as an encoding channel. The best you can do is to manually split the data and layer marks with the desired angles; for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [0, 1, 0, -1],
        "y": [1, 0, -1, 0],
        "name": ["UP", "RIGHT", "BOTTOM", "LEFT"],
        "angle": [180, 270, 0, 90],
    }
)

base = alt.Chart(data).encode(x="x", y="y", text="name")

layers = [
    base.transform_filter(alt.datum.name == name).mark_text(angle=angle)
    for (name, angle) in zip(data.name, data.angle)
]

alt.layer(*layers)
```

[image]